# Staggered Average and Standard Deviation of incomplete dataset

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, pooling, aggregation

I have an AxBxC matrix of measurements, from which an arbitrarily-sized-and-distributed number of measurements have been deemed invalid and removed (i.e. that matrix contains a mostly random assortment of null entries).

I need to progressively collapse this matrix of measurements to a single average, range, and standard deviation. Specifically, I need to collapse the matrix in this order: AxBxC > 1xBxC > 1x(B/2)xC > 1x1xC. The B > B/2 step is because 1/2 of the B measurements actually stack; that is, each entry in the 1x(B/2)xC array is the sum of 2 adjacent measurements in the 1xBxC array.

At each stage of this consolidation, I want to have both the average and standard deviation (maybe also the min/max range) of the dataset.

Step 1) I assume I've done correctly: average and stdev along axis A to create a 1xBxC matrix. This hides/buries the missing entries, allowing me to continue the consolidation.

Step 2) I start struggling here. I've summed the average values from the previous step in pairs (1xBxC > 1x(B/2)xC), but am unsure how to correctly calculate the standard deviation. At present I've just taken the standard deviation of the original dataset (All entries across Dimension A for a given pair of entries in Dimension B), which I don't think is correct.

Step 3) Average of Averages dimension B, again unsure how to calculate stdev.

I will note that I have barely touched statistics in the past ~13yrs, and so am unlikely to understand the meaning of any given mathematical symbol in an equation.